# What is the correct name to use with /give for Lapis Lazuli?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

In Minecraft, when cheats are enabled you can give yourself items using the command `/give [user] [item] [count]`, e.g. `/give user45623 dirt 32`.

What is the item name to use for Lapis Lazuli? I've tried `lapis_lazuli`, `lapis`, `lazuli`, `dye4`, and `dye_4`, but it's none of those.

Comment: `/give pretty_blue_things`, obviously

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Lapis Lazuli is a dye. Each dye shares the same name and relies on the data value to determine what type of dye it is. To spawn it in, you need to specify that data value using `/give`'s fourth argument:

```
/give <player> <item> [count] [datavalue]
```

To give a player one Lapis Lazuli, you need to specify a data value of `4`:

```
/give <player> dye 1 4
```

These data values encompass other items too, like cocoa beans, bone meal, and ink sacs, which have data values 3, 15, and 0, respectively.

Source: [Data value of Lapis Lazuli](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Lapis_Lazuli#Data_values)

Comment: Now I understand how wood works too! Do you have any idea what a ****ing nightmare it is just trying to look up how to give yourself wood? ...that came out wrong.

Comment: This answer is outdated. Please see my new answer below.

Answer (score 7):

From [the wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Lapis_Lazuli#Data_values):

Lapis Lazuli has the ID name `minecraft:dye`, with a data value of 4. So do this:

```
/give player minecraft:dye 1 4
```

To get one of them.

Comment: Damn. You ninja'd me. +1

Comment: @aytimothy - sorry! :)

Comment: FYI, prepending the ID names with "minecraft:" is totally unnecessary and just making more work for yourself. I gave Tim the check because his answer was slightly more thorough, but you get an upvote

Comment: @user45623 - no problem, glad we both could help. Yes, the 'minecraft' bit is not needed because that's the default namespace. I included it for clarity though, because it's unambiguous then. By the way, you can use /help to get the summary of any command, if you forget (this one is not particularly obvious, I have to admit).

Answer (score 1):

## 1.13+ Update

Data values have been abolished in favour of separate item IDs. So now instead of `dye` with the data value for a colour, they now go by the item name. Lapis Lazuli's item name is `minecraft:lapis_lazuli`

```
/give @s minecraft:lapis_lazuli
```

Answer (score 0):

To give lapis lazuli to yourself:

```
/give @s lapis_lazuli <amount>
```