# What's the ID for lapis lazuli

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

So I want to summon lapis using a command block in 1.12.2 But I don't know what ID it is.
I tried `Lapis lazuli` and `dye4` and `dyeblue` and `bluedye` and `dye_4` and nothing worked.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the correct name to use with /give for Lapis Lazuli?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/257330/what-is-the-correct-name-to-use-with-give-for-lapis-lazuli)

Answer (score 2):

According to [MinecraftItemIDs.com](https://minecraftitemids.com/), the Item ID for lapis lazuli is minecraft:lapis_lazuli. The ID that you would need to use instead of the last one, is **minecraft:dye** because the version that you are using is 1.12.2.

Here is the command you would want to use to give yourself lapis:

`/give @p minecraft:dye 1`

You can change the number 1 to whatever number of lapis you want.

Comment: You need to specify the type of dye, so the correct command for lapis lazuli would be `/give @p minecraft:dye <amount> 4`